# Is it possible to tell the difference between hotlinking and regular linking of images using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, hotlinking

I think the answer to this is no, but ideally I would like to be able to allow image hotlinking, but redirect regular links. For example, if somebody uses this, it should work as expected:

```
<img src='http://mysite.com/image.jpg'/>
```

But if they use this, it would redirect to a different page upon visiting:

```
<a href='http://mysite.com/image.jpg'>Click Here</a>
```

I believe `$HTTP_REFERER` is the same, regardless of the two methods. Is there any other clever way to distinguish between the two?

Comment: Not an answer as such, but very related information on a technique to stop people embedding your images, while allowing them to link to your images, showing a different page.  With a bit of tweaking, I think you could accomplish your requirements.  [http://www.alistapart.com/articles/hotlinking/](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/hotlinking/)

Comment: Unfortunately, that method won't work because the way it disallows hotlinking is that it just breaks the image by virtue of the link sending HTML headers. I need the image to send image headers when hotlinked so that the image is embedded.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking it through over dinner and realised it only works by preventing hotlinking from non whitelisted referers.

Comment: You absolutely need to do it with an htaccess?

Comment: After more thought, I'm inclined to agree that this can't be done, at least not sensibly.  
A not-so-sensible solution (depending on the volume of requests involved), would be to rewrite all image requests from a referer other than your own to a script which scrapes the referring page to determine whether it came via an a tag or an img tag and deal with it appropriately (and caching the result so you don't have to scrape the next time)
EDIT: a more sensible compromise might be to rewrite requests from referers other than your own site to a watermarked version of the image.

Comment: @John - That's not a bad idea, re: watermarks. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many browsers send different `Accpet:` header in these two situations.

When requesting resource from `<img src="xxx">`:

```
Accept: */*
```

When requesting the url in address bar:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Comment: Typo: "Accpet". Also, "header" should probably be pluralized. (SO won't allow correction edits of less than 6 characters.)